# Hook_menu selective menu tab display

Tags: filter, drupal-7, hook-menu

I am using the following code to include a custom tab for my node types:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['node/%node/register']   =   array(
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments'  =>  array('access content'),
        'type'  =>  MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'title' =>  'Register',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

This has the effect of including a **register** tab for every node type. However, I need to include that tab for only page types and exclude it on all other type like article types etc.

What other directions can I consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to provide your own access callback that checks the node type, e.g.

```
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items['node/%node/register'] = array(
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_node_register_tab_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type'  =>  MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' =>  'Register',
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_node_register_tab_access($node) {
  $valid_types = array('page');
  return in_array($node->type, $valid_types);
}
```